# How do you get all the categories in a category group in a controller?

Tags: categories, controller

I want to get all the categories in a specific category group inside my controller. How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. This might help others:

```
$categories = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category)->group('handle');
```